# How to protect cast iron bathtub after heavy cleaning

Tags: bathtub, resurfacing

We have a cast iron bathtub that had a very heavy iron stain from our city's water supply. The surface was so rough that it was painful to use, I tried cleaning it with a wire brush attached to a drill, and it got rid of the stains and made the usable, gripping flesh, but not.

Afterwards the bath seemed nice and white. However my wife is worried that iron deposits will start to return unless I apply something to the surface of the bath.

The wire brushing definitely has removed some enamel, however not to the point where I'm seeing bare cast-iron.

Should I be worried about leaving the bath as-is? Or should I "go all the way" and use a grinder to resurface more of the bath (it has some other bad spots), and apply some sort of coating, and if so what coating is normal for a bath?

Comment: The end of the first paragraph is a bit confusing. Please revise.

Comment: There are products designed to add a glaze to bathtubs, but they often come with warnings not to use them where you'd stand since they're slippery. There are also companies that specialize in resurfacing tubs, and there are DIY products for that. Whether you do these is your prerogative. Did you have a more specific question?